# spring statemachine stuck at join state

Tags: spring-statemachine

I'm trying to model cash accepting machine.

My StateMachine configuration is below. I omitted some states and events that are not critical.

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states) throws Exception {
    states
        .withStates()
            .initial(States.INIT, initAction())
            .state(States.CONNECTED)
            .and()
            .withStates()
                .parent(States.CONNECTED)
                .initial(States.READY)
                .state(States.READY)
                .fork(States.ACCEPTING_CASH_FORK)
                .state(States.ACCEPTING_CASH)
                .join(States.ACCEPTING_CASH_JOIN)
                .choice(States.PROCESSING_CASH)
                .state(States.PRINTING_RECEIPT, printingReceiptAction(), null)
            .and()
            .withStates()
                .parent(States.ACCEPTING_CASH)
                .initial(States.BNR_CASH_IN_START)
                .state(States.BNR_CASH_IN_END)
                .end(States.BNR_CASH_IN_EXIT)
            .and()
            .withStates()
                .parent(States.ACCEPTING_CASH)
                .initial(States.CNR_CASH_IN_START)
                .state(States.CNR_CASH_IN_END)
                .end(States.CNR_CASH_IN_EXIT)
            .and();
}

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions) throws Exception {
    transitions
        .withExternal()
            .source(States.INIT).target(States.CONNECTED)
            .and()
        .withExternal()
            .source(States.READY)
            .target(States.ACCEPTING_CASH_FORK)
            .event(Events.ACCEPT_CASH)
            .and()
        .withFork()
            .source(States.ACCEPTING_CASH_FORK)
            .target(States.BNR_CASH_IN_START).target(States.CNR_CASH_IN_START)
            .and()
        .withExternal()
            .source(States.BNR_CASH_IN_END)
            .target(States.BNR_CASH_IN_EXIT)
            .event(Events.BNR_CASH_IN_END_COMPLETED)
            .and()
        .withExternal()
            .source(States.CNR_CASH_IN_END)
            .target(States.CNR_CASH_IN_EXIT)
            .event(Events.CNR_CASH_IN_END_COMPLETED)
            .and()
        .withJoin()
            .source(States.BNR_CASH_IN_EXIT).source(States.CNR_CASH_IN_EXIT).target(States.ACCEPTING_CASH_JOIN)
            .and()
        .withExternal()
            .source(States.ACCEPTING_CASH_JOIN)
            .target(States.PROCESSING_CASH)
            .and()
        .withChoice()
            .source(States.PROCESSING_CASH)
            .first(States.DISPENSING_CASH_FORK, dispensingCashGuard(), dispensingCashAction())
            .last(States.PRINTING_RECEIPT)
            .and();
}
```

I also configured a listener for debugging purpose.

```
@Bean
public StateMachineListener<States, Events> listener() {
    return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(State<States, Events> from, State<States, Events> to) {
            log.info("State change from " + (from != null ? from.getId() : from) + " to " + to.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void stateMachineStarted(StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine) {
            log.info("StateMachine uuid " + stateMachine.getUuid() + " state " + stateMachine.getState().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void transition(Transition<States, Events> transition) {
            Trigger<States, Events> trigger = transition.getTrigger();
            State<States, Events> source = transition.getSource();
            State<States, Events> target = transition.getTarget();
            log.info("Transition trigger " + (trigger != null ? trigger.getEvent() : trigger) + 
                " source " + (source != null ? source.getId() : source) + 
                " target " + (target != null ? target.getId() : target) + " kind " + transition.getKind());
        }

    };
}
```

The problem is at **ACCEPTING_CASH_JOIN** join which statemachine is supposed to be in when 2 states are reached **BNR_CASH_IN_EXIT** and **CNR_CASH_IN_EXIT**. But in logs statemachine doesn't reach it.

```
2017-06-30 19:59:06.891  INFO 3776 --- [       Thread-9] k.d.c.config.StateMachineConfiguration   : StateMachine uuid 52e51cf0-06f0-4efa-8d05-1717bf869239 state CONNECTED
2017-06-30 19:59:06.891  INFO 3776 --- [       Thread-9] k.d.c.config.StateMachineConfiguration   : State change from null to CNR_CASH_IN_END
2017-06-30 19:59:06.892  INFO 3776 --- [       Thread-8] k.d.c.config.StateMachineConfiguration   : Transition trigger CNR_CASH_IN_END_COMPLETED source CNR_CASH_IN_END target CNR_CASH_IN_EXIT kind EXTERNAL
2017-06-30 19:59:06.892  INFO 3776 --- [       Thread-8] k.d.c.config.StateMachineConfiguration   : State change from CNR_CASH_IN_END to CNR_CASH_IN_EXIT

2017-06-30 19:59:06.924  INFO 3776 --- [       Thread-8] k.d.c.config.StateMachineConfiguration   : StateMachine uuid 52e51cf0-06f0-4efa-8d05-1717bf869239 state CONNECTED
2017-06-30 19:59:06.924  INFO 3776 --- [       Thread-8] k.d.c.config.StateMachineConfiguration   : State change from null to BNR_CASH_IN_END
2017-06-30 19:59:07.146  INFO 3776 --- [       Thread-8] k.d.c.config.StateMachineConfiguration   : Transition trigger BNR_CASH_IN_END_COMPLETED source BNR_CASH_IN_END target BNR_CASH_IN_EXIT kind EXTERNAL
2017-06-30 19:59:07.146  INFO 3776 --- [       Thread-8] k.d.c.config.StateMachineConfiguration   : State change from BNR_CASH_IN_END to BNR_CASH_IN_EXIT

2017-06-30 19:59:27.239 DEBUG 3776 --- [  XNIO-2 task-4] k.d.c.w.rest.StateMachineQueryResource   : [CONNECTED, ACCEPTING_CASH, BNR_CASH_IN_EXIT, CNR_CASH_IN_EXIT]
```

the last line is my way of checking current state by calling method on statemachine **stateMachine.getState().getIds()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you mind trying two things separately

1. Change those end states to normal states.
2. Instead of joining by end states, join by their parent state(ACCEPTING_CASH).

I didn't yet check if there are tests for this particular use case to verify if it should work or not. Theory is that terminal states cannot have outgoing transitions, thus join may not work.

Comment: I tried both options. First one solved the issue, the second one did not. Thank you!